Tomcat 8.5.98 server.xml's ErrorReportValve not handling 50X errors
I have a problem with tomcat configuration, which does not handle 50X errors when thrown. I'm using server.xml with this configuration :
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
      showReport="false" showServerInfo="false"
      errorCode.400="static/400.html"
      errorCode.401="static/401.html"
      errorCode.403="static/403.html"
      errorCode.404="static/404.html"
      errorCode.405="static/405.html"
      errorCode.408="static/408.html"
      errorCode.413="static/413.html"
      errorCode.500="static/500.html"
      errorCode.503="static/503.html"
    />

all 40X errors are well handled, but not the 500 and 503 (files exist in the path and have same access right as 40X).
Am I missing something ?
For my tests, I change the name of my datasource for example (to force HTTP error 500).

I know it's been a while,b ut they way I read the documentation, showReport and showServierInfo both set to false is supposed to send just the status code... it doesn't work in 9.0.20, but that's what I got to thus far. Did you get any further these past few months?
